# Stop a tkinter subwindow (from Topleve()) being resized

Tags: python, tkinter, resize, toplevel

I know how to stop my main tkinter window being resized with:
`self.mainWin.resizable(False,False)`

However, when I make a subwindow class, I do this:

```
self.subWin = tk.Toplevel(parent.mainWin)
self.subWin.resizable(False,False)
```

which does not give any errors, but I can still resize the subwindow. Is there a trick to stopping resize of a subwindow created from *Toplevel()*?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the windows' titles: `mainWin.wm_title("main")` and `subWin.wm_title("sub")`. This will tell you which window is which. When I ran your code, the toplevel was not resizable (so it worked), but it was not on top either. Depending on what your full code is, maybe the problem is that the toplevel is behind the main window, and the two are getting confused. To fix this, you can call `mainWin.lower()`. This puts it behind the toplevel.

Answer (score 0):

What's confusing me is that I have another program from which I copied the window code, and that one behaves just fine. It's the new one, copied almost verbaitm, that doesn't. Here is the 'new' code. (I tried the `lower()` thing, but it didn't work, regardless that doesn't appear in the old program I wrote where it DOES work, which is what has me scratching my head).

```
class HarmonyExplorerMainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
      
        #____________________________________________________________
        # ----------------------- Main Window -----------------------
        
        self.mainWin = tk.Tk()
        self.mainWin.title('Harmony Explorer  by Stuart Christmas')
        MainWidth = 1000
        MainHeight = 655
        
        self.mainWin.geometry(str(MainWidth)+'x'+str(MainHeight))   # width x height
        self.mainWin.resizable(False,False)

<< NEW SUB-WINDOW IN A DIFFERENT FILE ALTOGETHER >>:

class CustomizeWindow():
    def __init__(self,parent):
                
        #____________________________________________________________
        # ----------------------- Main window ----------------------- 
        
        CustomWin = tk.Toplevel(parent.mainWin)
        CustomWin.title('Customize Scale')
        CustomWin.geometry("485x238")
        CustomWin.resizable=(False,False)
```

This code work fine in my older (totally different) program, both windows are NOT resizable. But in this verbatim copy (aside from the window and variable names), the main window in the first code chunk is not resizable (great), but the subwindow created from the lower code still is. Driving me crazy! I've tried messing around with `grab_set()` and `focus_set()` too, but always look back to the working code and wonder what's different. Everything else in the window works just fine, including using variables from parent (parent.x etc), so I know I'm calling it just fine...

*(EDIT: I notice my second class def ends with ()... which I don't think is right (another question maybe) but that didn't fix it...)*